# How I can overwrite a branch with another one?

Tags: git, git-flow

While I am developing I want to continue my work into another branch but base my work instead from master into another branch. For deployment management and workflow I use `git flow`.

In my case I created a feature branch:

```
git flow feature start MYPROJECT_2311
```

But the feature branch that I want to continue the development is `feature/MYPROJECT_2322`. This is a common occurence because I want to extend a feature branch with new features while I wait for one to be deployed.

How I can do that?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "continue my work into another branch" and "base my work from master into another branch". Did you mean "continue my work **in** another branch" and "**rebase** my work from master **onto** another branch"?

Comment: I mean I colueage of mine did some changes into a feature branch and I need to develop more changes but whilst the branch is in code review state and in PR. Hence, I do not want to confuse my boss with more changes, so I want to get the coleagues work into another branch and develop my changes.

Comment: just move to master before creating the branch. The new branch uses whatever branch you are in when you create it. This is a core git feature, so unless they explicitly change it, it should be the same for any program that uses git.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset it into the feature branch you want to continue.

1. Fetch and pull (It is optional but gives you an essence of current code state)

   ```
   git fetch
   # Usually develop is the default develop branch in git flow
   # Change into the appropriate name that indicated the branch for development
   git checkout develop
   git git pull origin develop
   ```
2. Create a new branch (Skip if you already done this step)

   ```
   git flow feature MYPROJECT_2311
   ```
3. reset in to the feature branch you want to continue

   ```
   git reset --hard feature/MYPROJECT_2322
   ```
4. (Optionally but due to slow deployments you may want to merge anything to latest changes)

   ```
   git merge develop
   ```

   In this case you may have some conflicts that you'll need to fix by yourself.

Comment: You can do this in a one line command: `git switch -c feature/MYPROJECT_2311 feature/MYPROJECT_2322`